# How do I insert a sequence of rows in a MySQL database

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, sequence

I have an existing table, with which I would like to do the equivalent of the following:

```
insert into the_table set col0=1, col1=0, col2=0;
insert into the_table set col0=2, col1=0, col2=0;
insert into the_table set col0=3, col1=0, col2=0;
...
...
insert into the_table set col0=255, col1=0, col2=0;
```

Because this is something that I'll be doing interactively now and again, I'd like to know how to reduce it to a single statement and shove it in via the console every so often.

EDIT:

Typing the following at the console is NOT realistic:

```
insert into the_table (col1, col2, col3) values (0,0,0),(1,0,0)....(255,0,0);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bit hacky, and technically this would be two queries:

```
SET @i:=0;
INSERT INTO the_table (col0,col1,col2)
SELECT @i:=@i+1,0,0 FROM SomeTable LIMIT 255;
```

Where `SomeTable` is any table in your database that has at least 255 rows.

Comment: You can also use a built-in table as `SomeTable`. For example, the cross join of `time_zone` with itself provides you with 3.2 million rows.

Answer (score 3):

```
insert into the_table (col0, col1, col2) values
(1, 0, 0),
(2, 0, 0),
(3, 0, 0)
```

I can't speak for MySQL, but SQL Server limits this to 1000 rows per statement.

Answer (score 2):

```
INSERT INTO the_table
    (col0, col1, col2)
    VALUES
    (1, 0, 0),
    (2, 0, 0),
    (3, 0, 0),
    ...
    (255, 0, 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also put those values into another table, and do it with an [INSERT..SELECT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html):

```
INSERT INTO the_table (col0, col1, col2)
SELECT col0, col1, col2 FROM the_table_defaults
```

Comment: OP: My table is a temporary, created from a previous query, so I don't have defaults to fall back on.